# formatBlock in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer, formatting, internet-explorer-11, execcommand

There is a quirck in Internet Explorer that forces you to enclose element names with angle brackets when formatting text with execCommand and formatBlock. 
All other browsers accept `document.execCommand("formatBlock", false, "H1")` while Internet Explorer requires `document.execCommand("formatBlock", false, "<H1>")`

IE10 and below are detectable with the following trick:

```
isIE = function () {
    var userAgent   = navigator.userAgent,
        isIE        = userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") !== -1 && userAgent.indexOf("Opera") === -1;

    return isIE;
}
```

Internet Explorer 11 breaks browser detection by pretending to be Firefox. I know it is frowned upon to do browser detection and I should do feature detection instead. In this case the feature is there but it is not consistent.

Is there another way to consistently apply block formatting without relying on browser detection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`execCommand()` returns `true` if the command is successful, or `false` otherwise. Hence you can do something like this:

```
if (!document.execCommand('FormatBlock', null, 'H1')) {
    document.execCommand('FormatBlock', null, '<H1>');
}
```

Though other browsers seem also to work with `<H1>` as well...

Comment: Did you find this out by trial and error or is the false/true return documented somewhere? Neither [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla) or [quirksmode](http://quirksmode.org/dom/execCommand.html) mention this.If you have a reliable source for this kind of stuff, feel free to share.

Comment: [`execCommand()` return value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536419%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) can be found at least at MSDN. `'<H1>'` as an argument I've just tested with newest Chrome and FF, like I said: "seem to work".